# dynamic hosts for NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am looking to build a server with NodeJS that will accept requests from a dynamic lists of hosts.  For example, I might have a customer sign up with the domain `"joesdomain.com"` and another with `"timsdomain.net"`.  These values are stored in a database table via another process.  It was my hope that [diet.js](http://dietjs.com/) would handle this, but I am not sure it supports this use case.  Most of the examples I have found are more like subdomains like mydomain.com/joesdomain or mydomain.com/timsdomain.  I would think I could read the database for a list of approved domains, and then use those values in my route mapping?

Here is my anticipated flow:

- Customer signs up for an account, we acquire the domain name and have it pointed to our host IP.
- When visitors to the new domain name, my NodeJS server will see the request and then handle the routing (I anticipate 90% of the same routes).

Does anyone know if this is possible, and hopefully point me in the right direction.  I won't want to have to modify code and redeploy code just to map these domains.

Comment: What do you mean to accept requests from a list of domains.  A request comes from an IP address, not necessarily from a host.  You could do a reverse lookup to try to figure out what domain a given IP address is associated with, but that is problematic in a number of ways as many IP addresses belong to corporations and are not associated with a domain.

Comment: Do you mean that you want your single server to accept requests for a list of domains so a request to http://joesdomain.com would go to your server?  If so, that requires those domains to be pointed at your server via DNS and your server can then tell which domain it was via an HTTP header.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to explain.  So if joesdomain.com resolves to my IP, and NodeJS gets the request, it will need to inspect the HTTP Header to confirm the origin?  For the average user, does this require they do anything special other than just providing the URL in their browser?

Comment: The browser will set the [Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) for you without the user doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about directing multiple different domains to your server, then your server can tell which domain the request was directed at by looking at the [Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) in the HTTP request.  The browser will set that header automatically without the end user doing anything.

If you look at section 5 in [this spec](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-03.html), it says:

> Whenever a user agent issues an HTTP request, the user agent MUST
>   include exactly one HTTP header named "Origin" that conforms to the
>   following ABNF [RFC5234] grammar:

Comment: if I hope to have 1000's of unique domains that point to my host, all served up by this NodeJS instance (using dietjs or turtle.io) is this going to be a problem for per-host connection limit (not really sure what that is yet)

Comment: @sonoerin - There's no per-host anything on the server side.  They are just incoming individual HTTP requests that your server examines the origin header to see what domain they were intended for.  Now, if you have to look up the origin on your server to determine what to do for the request, then that's on your server to have an efficient host lookup scheme (probably can just keep them all in memory).  A single browser has a per-host connection limit, but not a server.  I assume these connections are coming from lots of different browsers so a browser per-host connection limit shouldn't be.